# Is it possible to do math operation on value bound to property in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, binding

I've an Angular component that receive my model. In my model, I've a rating, this rating is expressed in %, between 0 and 1.

for my view, I'm using ngb-rating, which allows me to set the rating + the maximum value.

I need to display this value over 6 stars, so I currently have this:

```
<ngb-rating [(rate)]="topic.rating" [starTemplate]="t" [readonly]="true" max="6"></ngb-rating>
```

The issue is that my value only change between 0 and 1, so I should be able to have this value between 0 and 6.

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
<ngb-rating [(rate)]="(topic.rating *6)" [starTemplate]="t" [readonly]="true" max="6"></ngb-rating>
```

my topic is only an interface, it's generated from the server, which don't care about how it should be displayed.

How should I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use "bannana sintax", you can not use a function or an expresion -you're telling Angular that can change a "function"-, so you need use the properties [rate] and (rateChange) to show/change the value of your variable

```
<ngb-rating [rate]="topic.rating*6" (rateChange)="topic.rating=$event/6"
       [starTemplate]="t" [readonly]="true" max="6"></ngb-rating>
```

NOTE: if is readOnly you can use only [rate]

[simple stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cfegkw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Nice, I'm stupid, didn't think it was because of the non-read-only stuff! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1st Approach 
You can do all the maths inside a function and call that in template

```
<ngb-rating [(rate)]="rating" [starTemplate]="t" [readonly]="true" max="6"></ngb-rating>
```

you can set a variable in that function like this and use that var in template

```
getRating(rating) {
this.rating = rating *6;
}
```

2nd Approach

After looking at ngb-rating 
I think you should be able to use [rate]="topic.rating*6" in template only
as there is no two way binding you don't need to use [(rate)]

Comment: Is n't calling a function from template a bad practice? as the function gets called on each change detection cycle.

Comment: And I just tried, it doesn't work for me: `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token '=' at column 24 in [getRating(topic.rating)=$event] in ng:///HoroscopeModule/HoroscopeListComponent.html@5:41 (".name }}</h4>
  <p *ngFor="let topic of horoscope.topics">
   {{topic.name}}: <ngb-rating [(rate)]="[ERROR ->]getRating(topic.rating)" [starTemplate]="t" [readonly]="true" max="6"></ngb-rating>
  </p>`

Comment: Instead of this 'getRating(topic.rating)=$event'. you need to evaluate the expression in the function in component and return the result. That will resolve the template parsing error. Although I don't quite like the idea of calling a function from template

Comment: @user8351493, if you use "bannana sintax", you can not use a function or an expresion